# How to produce a string with the number of letters determined automatically in R?

Tags: r

I know the title is quite confusing and I do not know how to improve it. So let me give a sample to make things clear.

I want to produce a string like

```
"ccccccc"
```

it's so easy to achieve if I know the number of  c here, however this is not the case, since number of c is determined by another thing ,say the number of columns of a data frame, things happen if you are using **xtable**  in R to print out your result while want maintain the alignment in the way you desire. The WORST thing may be you need to count the number of columns of the specific data frame you are dealing with and  go to the line of code like:

```
align = "llcccccc"
```

pathetically push the button on your keyboard and count like '1,2,3,4...', every time you want to print.So as a lazy fresh coding man,  I want to go like this:

```
align = paste0("ll",rep("c",dim(faketable)[2]))
```

where **faketable** is the data frame need to be print out. However, this code will give me :

```
"llc" "llc" "llc" "llc" "llc" "llc" "llc" "llc"
```

and what I WANT IS :

```
"llcccccccc"
```

Is there anyone could kindly help me on this? Your time and knowledge would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the `collapse` argument that you're looking for:

```
paste0("ll", paste(rep("c", 5), collapse=""))
## [1] "llccccc"
```

Comment: Thanks Aaron, This does work. I would take that as an answer

Comment: You're welcome, but you really should upgrade and use `strrep`.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `strrep` with `paste`

```
paste0('ll', strrep('c', 5))
#[1] "llccccc"
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment @akrun, which package does "strrep" function in ?  I can't find  it in Rstudio and Google. Would you please kindly tell me?

Comment: @JasonGoal  It is from `base R`  No need for any packages.  Which version of R you have?

Comment: May be that is just in base and only available from R version 3.4, mine is R version 3.2.5 (2016-04-14)

Comment: @JasonGoal  Probably, it was introduced in R 3.3. or so.  It is optimized